# How to comment in a windows.tmux file

Tags: tmux, byobu

My `~/.byobu/windows.tmux` file is getting a bit complex and I would like to document it with comments.

How to insert comments in Byobu's `windows.tmux` file?

Using `#` as seen below results in a `unknown command: #` error message.

```
# Start monitors for each customer
new-session -n va /home/me/bin/monitor-1.sh;
new-window -n vk /home/me/bin/monitor-2.sh;
new-window -n vd /home/me/bin/monitor-3.sh;
new-window -n su bash ;
```

Versions:

```
$ byobu --version
byobu version 5.92
tmux 1.9
```

Comment: Which version of `tmux` are you using?

Comment: FYI, the `byobu` developer frequently answers `byobu` questions in AskUbuntu.  Maybe asking there would help?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [manual page](http://manpg.es/byobu.1)

> Users  can  create  a  list  of  windows  to  launch  at   startup in  `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows`   and  `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows.tmux`.
>   **This file is the  same  syntax  as  `~/.screenrc`  and  `~/.tmuxrc`**,  each  line specifying a window, as described in `screen(1)` or `tmux(1)`

The standard comment character in a `tmux` configuration file is `#`. Anything after a `#` is ignored.

```
# Set the default keybindings
set -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-b
bind C-a send-prefix
...
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I get: `unknown command: #`

Comment: Very strange. I've just double checked the documentation and the `windows.tmux` format is the same as that of `~/.tmux.conf`. Can you paste an excerpt of your file in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to comment lines with a `#` character. It may be that this character has to start a line and entries like `set ... # setting a new value` are not allowed.

Comment: I've just tested, and in `~/.tmux.conf`, anything after a `#` that's not in quotes is ignored (as expected)

Comment: @mjturner: This question is about `~/.byobu/windows.tmux` which might be different from `~/.tmux.conf`.